# Outlook plugin and LoginHistory

Tags: soql, remote-access, outlook

Is there a way to recreate the function that shows and counts Outlook plugin accesses on the user detail page ?

My aim is to see which users connected successfully through Outlook, and when, so as to know who can be assigned an SSO profile again, on the same view ( VF Page if needed).

See on User detail page, section "Remote Access", and section "Login History": what can be the relation between remote access count and the login history data ?

**edit:**
I would love so much that this did not throw an error, because the result of the following is exactly what i need:

```
select UserId, LoginTime, Application, Status from LoginHistory where Application like '%Outlook%' and Status = 'Success' group by UserId order by LoginTime desc
```

*i'm actually writing a workaround in Apex*

Comment: Do you encounter `field 'Status' can not be filtered in query call`?

Comment: Yep, precisely.

Answer (score 1):

In one of the sessions on dreamforce, one of the speakers mentioned that a "workaround" that you can do to have better insights on the login history is to export the login history and then import that information again in a custom object.

You can export the login history via "Manage Users > Login History".

Importing, you can do with the tools of your choice like jitterbit dataloader, dataloader.io etc.

You wouldn't have real-time info because you don't want to be doing this export import daily but you could do this export for example on a monthly base.

Then, as soon as you have this info in a custom object, you can do many nice things with it offcourse.

But indeed, keep in mind that improvements are comming for this functionality out of the box (safe harbor), so you probably wouldn't want to invest too much time in it right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible actually. Remote access details are not available through the API, and one must use the user page layout to see if the user connected remotely with the Outlook plugin.

There will be improvements in Summer 13 release around the connections details, so let's wait until deployment to find out.

To this day, only a very motivated coder might succeed, maybe by writing a web crawler surfing the standard interface... hacker style !